# Using single Command line and variables.

Tags: command-line, variables

how do you define a variable to an integer at the command line. For example if i want to assign A=22 and B=23 and then have the A and B = a separate variable such as C..? I am confused on the syntax of this at the command line.  I understand how to set variables in a script but how would i do it from a command line using only 1 line?

Comment: what language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: What OS are you trying to do this on?

Answer (score 0):

```
A=22; B=23; ((C=A+B)); echo $A $B $C
```

Assuming Bash or Korn shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
set A=22
set B=23
set A=%C%
set B=%C%
```

In windows bat-files. Also be careful not to use any extra spaces in batch file syntax. It can screw up everything.